# how to apply unique condition for a data frame like here

Tags: r, unique, dplyr, plyr

Here is reproducible data

```
df <- structure(list(df_A = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("2016-05-10", "2016-05-11", 
    "2016-05-12", "2016-05-14", "2016-05-15", "2016-05-17", "2016-05-18", 
    "2016-05-19"), class = "factor"), df_B = structure(1:13, .Label = c("SO-101", 
    "SO-102", "SO-103", "SO-104", "SO-105", "SO-106", "SO-107", "SO-108", 
    "SO-109", "SO-110", "SO-111", "SO-112", "SO-113"), class = "factor"), 
        df_C = c(1113L, 2312L, 2312L, 2314L, 2314L, 2546L, 2315L, 
        2315L, 2315L, 5689L, 2546L, 2546L, 2312L)), .Names = c("df_A", 
    "df_B", "df_C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L
    ))
> df1
         df_A   df_B df_C
1  2016-05-10 SO-101 1113
2  2016-05-11 SO-102 2312
3  2016-05-11 SO-103 2312
4  2016-05-12 SO-104 2314
5  2016-05-12 SO-105 2314
6  2016-05-14 SO-106 2546
7  2016-05-15 SO-107 2315
8  2016-05-15 SO-108 2315
9  2016-05-15 SO-109 2315
10 2016-05-17 SO-110 5689
11 2016-05-18 SO-111 2546
12 2016-05-18 SO-112 2546
13 2016-05-19 SO-113 2312

let say
df_B column represents the production order.
df_C column represents the product certificate
```

For every production order there can be a same certificate as the previous order or can be a different one. I want to know date of product certificate changed.
So i want to subset the rows in df_c column by using unique, but in that case i will loose the row with different production order, but same certificate which produced later.

df2 is my desired dataframe.

```
df2
        df_A   df_B df_C
1 2016-05-10 SO-101 1113
2 2016-05-11 SO-102 2312
3 2016-05-12 SO-104 2314
4 2016-05-14 SO-106 2546
5 2016-05-15 SO-107 2315
6 2016-05-17 SO-110 5689
7 2016-05-18 SO-111 2546
8 2016-05-19 SO-113 2312
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeping unique values is equivalent to removing duplicated values. `duplicated` returns indexes of duplicate rows, so we can filter out rows that are duplicated in columns 1 and 3:

```
df[!duplicated(df[c(1, 3)]), ]
         df_A   df_B df_C
1  2016-05-10 SO-101 1113
2  2016-05-11 SO-102 2312
4  2016-05-12 SO-104 2314
6  2016-05-14 SO-106 2546
7  2016-05-15 SO-107 2315
10 2016-05-17 SO-110 5689
11 2016-05-18 SO-111 2546
13 2016-05-19 SO-113 2312
```

Also worth pointing out that the default `duplicated` argument is `fromLast = FALSE`, so this will keep the first instance of each `df_A` and `df_C` column. As long as your data is sorted by date to start with, this will give you the date the certificate changed as you request.